# EF Core Update SubjectIdentifierNotUniqueError Error when doing an update

Tags: sql-server, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am grabbing a list of Subjects from my database and looping through them to decrypt some of the columns in the database.  It was zipping along just fine, then hit a record and then all the remaining records started giving this error:

> SubjectIdentifierNotUniqueErrorABCBB8D0-00C2-427C-8B79-04250B7133A48126A83E-BAAA-40B2-ADF2-437CE8AABDA3Attempted insert or update of non-unique Subject Identifer
> The transaction ended in the trigger. The batch has been aborted.

The error type thrown is Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException

So I looked up the record in the database and there is only one record in the subjects table with this UserId.  Here is the code I am using to update

```
var subjects = context.Subjects.ToList();
    foreach (var subject in subjects)
    {
        //decrypt each subject and then update them in the database
        var decryptedSubject = encrypt.DecryptSubjects(subject, cols.SubjectColumns);
        if (decryptedSubject != null)
        {
           
            subject.Code = decryptedSubject.Code;
            subject.FirstName = decryptedSubject.FirstName;
            subject.LastName = decryptedSubject.LastName;
            subject.MiddleName = decryptedSubject.MiddleName;
            subject.PreferredName = decryptedSubject.PreferredName;
            subject.Gender = decryptedSubject.Gender;
            subject.LastNameInitial = decryptedSubject.LastNameInitial;
            subject.CodeDisplay = decryptedSubject.CodeDisplay;
            context.Update(subject);
            try
            {
                context.SaveChanges();
                Console.WriteLine($"{decryptedSubject.LastName},{decryptedSubject.FirstName} decrypted...");
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error decrypting...");
            }
           
        }
    }
```

Checking the values in subject that are not updated, the values are not changed, the values that are updated (the decrypted values) are set correctly.  It is when it gets to the context.SaveChanges() that his error is thrown.

What does this error mean?  It is not duplicated, I checked that.

Comment: "The transaction ended in the trigger" you have a trigger in your database... you need to check out what it is doing.

Comment: I think 'context.Update(subject)' is redundant and not required. And also bring context.savechanges() outside the foreach loop to run everything in a transaction.

Comment: @DaleK that was it.  There was a trigger on the table that was firing off on each insert,update.  I disabled it and it appears to be working now.  Thanks.